# How to run R code chunks on different cores?

Tags: r, parallel-processing

Instead of creating multiple R scripts, I would like to create one R script where I can run different chunks on different cores simultaneously. To better understand, say these are three different R chunks that have a logical flow, I would like a library or function that allows me to assign a core to each R code chunk

SCRIPT 1

''' **run on all cores**
library(x)
library(y)
library(z)
'''

''' **run core 1**
print('Hello')
'''

''' **run core 1**
print('!')
'''

SCRIPT 2

''' **run core 2**
print('My')
'''

SCRIPT 3

''' **run core 3**
print('is')
'''

Current online information simply discusses about loops and other iterative processes but none that directly mentions how to assign cores to code chunks to my knowledge

Comment: Web searches will turn up many blogs about parallel processing in R, mentions of the `parallel` and `future` packages, and maybe even the CRAN Task View https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/HighPerformanceComputing.html. A little bit more reading will reveal that R is single threaded. Nothing is going to say how to put specific scripts on different cores because process allocation is the job of the OS, not R. I think the best you can do is run multiple processes and hope the OS runs them on different cores